# Finding the explicit formula for the given recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

This is the recurrence relation:$ a_n=4-a_{n-1}, a_2=-3$.I noticed that the result for even index of $a$ is always -3 and the result for odd index of $a$ is 7,But I don't know where to go with it.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(n):=\begin{cases}\text{even}(n)&\to-3,\\\text{odd}(n)&\to\ \ \ 7\end{cases}$$ is a valid answer.

---

If you really want a "formula",

$$2-5\cos(n\pi)$$
or
$$(10n)\bmod20-3.$$

Answer (score 1):

The natural way is induction. You have $a_2=-3$. Now take $k\in\Bbb N$ and assume that$$a_k=\begin{cases}-3&\text{ if $k$ is even}\\7&\text{ if $k$ is odd.}\end{cases}$$Then,\begin{align}a_{k+1}&=4-a_k\\&=\begin{cases}7&\text{ if $k$ is even}\\-3&\text{ if $k$ is odd.}\end{cases}\\&=\begin{cases}-3&\text{ if $k+1$ is even}\\7&\text{ if $k+1$ is odd.}\end{cases}\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Use [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

$$a_n=-3[n \equiv 0\pmod 2]+7[n \equiv 1\pmod 2]$$

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n-2=4-a_{n-1}-2=(-1)(a_{n-1}-2)$$
$\{a_n-2\}$ is a geometric sequence so
$$a_n-2=(-1)^{n-2}(a_2-2)=5(-1)^{n-1} \implies a_n = 2+5(-1)^{n-1}.$$